# PictureBoxSizeMode has no effects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, picturebox, visual-c#-express-2010

I am trying to manipulate some images using `C# (VS 2010)`. I have a Form which has a tab control with 7 tabs. Under each tab, I have a 900 x 750 picture box and I am trying to display images of size 1800 x 1500 in each of them using the paint event.

1. I tried setting the sizemode through the property window
2. I tried setting the sizemode property programmatically before painting the picturebox
3. I tried setting the sizemode property programmatically after painting the picturebox

Neither of those methods seem to have any effect on the images !! I still just see the top left quarter of the images. I guess the sizemode property is defaulting to normal mode. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: "...using the paint event..." SizeMode() will only affect the pictures if you set the Image() property of the PictureBox to your desired image.  If you want to manually draw them in the Paint() event then you'll need to do your own calculations and change DrawImage() accordingly.

Comment: If you are setting the Image() property of the PictureBox you shouldn't need to deal with the Paint() event at all.  *Set the Image() property from somewhere else, NOT the Paint() event!  =)

Comment: You only need to set the Image() property ONCE; the Paint() event will get called many times in your application.  If you post some code we can help you better.

Comment: Got it... Figured it out.
Thanks a lot @Idle_Mind